# Discord.py Commands within Commands?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've been thinking of making a Blackjack game in my discord bot, but I've hit a roadblock.

I obviously have the game which is summoned with the command `.blackjack`, and it works fine in generating the random values and sending the messages. However, I don't know how to make it so the player is able to say hit or stand after the message with the cards dealt is sent, for example.

```
@client.command()
async def blackjack(ctx):
    # (insert all random number gens, etc. here)
    
    await ctx.send(f"{dface1}{dsuit1} ({dvalue1}), {dface2}{dsuit2} ({dvalue2})")
    await ctx.send(f"(Dealer Total: {dtotal})")
    
    await ctx.send(f"{pface1}{psuit1} ({pvalue1}), {pface2}{psuit2} ({pvalue2})")
    await ctx.send(f"(Total: {ptotal})")
```

Now what? What do I do to run my next part of the code, which is whether or not the player hit or stands,  the dealer hitting and standing, etc.

Comment: check this [one](https://github.com/mitchellf/discord-blackjack-bot/blob/master/game.py) line no 76

Comment: you mean subcommands?

Answer (score 1):

`discord.py` has built-in subcommand support, here's an example:

```py
@commands.group(invoke_without_subcommand=True)
async def your_command_name(ctx):
    # Do something if there's not a subcommand invoked


@your_command_name.command()
async def subcommand_name(ctx, *args):
    # Do something

# To invoke
# {prefix}your_command_name subcommand_name some arguments here
```

Or you can simply wait for a message

```py
@client.command()
async def blackjack(ctx):
    # ...
    def check(message):
        """Checks if the message author is the same as the one that invoked the 
        command, and if the user chose a valid option"""
        return message.author == ctx.author and message.content.lower() in ['stand', 'hit']

    await ctx.send('Would you like to hit or stand?')

    message = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
    await ctx.send(f"You chose to `{message.content}`")

# To invoke
# {prefix}blackjack
# Would you like to hit or stand?
# stand
# You chose to `stand`
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know how to play Blackjack, so I'm afraid I won't be able to give you a full answer to your question. However I will say how you can achieve what you want. There are two ways you can go about doing this in my opinion.

#### Method 1

*Waiting for the user to react to your bot's message*

For this, you have to use:

```py
reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=60.0, check=check)
```

For example, say you are waiting for  or ️ from the user (This can mean hit and stand respectively). The code would look something like this:

```py
@client.command()
async def start(ctx):
    def check(reaction, user):
        return (user == ctx.author) and (str(reaction.emoji) == '' or str(reaction.emoji) == '️')

    async def sendMessage(msg):
        message = await ctx.send(msg)
        await message.add_reaction('')
        await message.add_reaction('️')

        try:
            reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout = 60.0, check = check)
        except:
            await message.clear_reactions()
            await ctx.send('No reaction received.')
        else:
            await message.clear_reactions()
            return reaction

        return 0

    reaction = str(await sendMessage('This is my message'))
```

This is a simple code to check if the user reacts with  or ️. You'll have to add more conditions and loops to get what you desire.

#### Method 2

*Waiting for the user to send a message*

For this, you have to use:

```py
msg = await client.wait_for('message', check = check, timeout = 60.0)
```

You'll have to then check if `msg` equals *hit* or *stand* or some short form like *h* or *s*. Also be sure to write a `check(author)` function that is called inside the `client.wait_for()` function (`check = check`) to check if the author is that same as the one that ran the command.

I hope you'll be able to come up with the code you are looking for after reading this answer.